# Best practice for using AJAX connection API in a VF page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, sforce.connection

I am using URL's as follows in a visual force page:

```
<script src="/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/soap/ajax/31.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Can you guys please let me know best practices while doing this? Things like should I use a static resource by getting the file instead of the URL? If so, how to get to the location where I can find the file?

How to use latest version of URL whenever SFDC updates it?

Or any performance impacts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Things like should I use a static resource by getting the file instead of the URL? If so, how to get to the location where I can find the file?

No, there's no need to use a static resource, and may actually harm performance and/or cause CORS script errors.

> How to use latest version of URL whenever SFDC updates it?

This is not a recommended practice. Changes from one API version to the next may break your JavaScript. Updates to code should be made manually after reviewing the release notes for API changes and testing the script after updating the API version. This is the reason why Salesforce supports so many different versions (at least 35 as of Spring '19), so that developers do not need to spend all their time updating older apps.

> Or any performance impacts?

No. Each API has relatively the same performance. The only thing that changes are new objects, fields, etc. Unless you have a need to use a new feature, you can upgrade at your leisure when you have time. Unlike many other languages and platforms (e.g. Java, .Net, etc), new API versions are not "bug fixes" or "security enhancements", but strictly new features. Any fixes to security or performance problems are implemented as "hot fixes", so developers never have to worry about upgrading an API version to gain the latest security features.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox this helped me a lot.